# Problem with PickCanvas when some items have been Transformed

Tags: java-3d

I have code that uses PickCanvas to work out where in 3D a user has clicked on a 3D model. The model is made from TriangleStrips. This all works fine.

Now if I add a Cylinder to the scene, that's OK too. But if I rotate the cylinder in a TransformGroup I can no longer click on it. Any ideas appreciated!

```
Transform3D tr = new Transform3D();
//tr.rotX(Math.PI/2); <--- uncommenting this line breaks PickCanvas
TransformGroup cylGroup = new TransformGroup(tr);               
tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_WRITE);
tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_READ);
tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_PARENT_READ);
tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_PICKABLE_READ);
tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_PICKABLE_WRITE);
cylGroup.addChild(cyl);     
tg.addChild(cylGroup);
```

This is how I'm reading the result of a mouse click:

```
pickCanvas.setShapeLocation(evt);
PickResult result = pickCanvas.pickClosest();
Point3d eyePos = pickCanvas.getStartPosition();
PickIntersection pi = result.getClosestIntersection(eyePos);
Point3d insectPt = pi.getPointCoordinates();
```

Comment: After a bit more fiddling it seems it's picking it correctly, but the co-ordinates I'm getting back are relative to the Cylinder, not my 3D world in general. The transform's effects aren't being reflected in the result from getClosestIntersection?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
Point3d insectPt = pi.getPointCoordinates();
Transform3D local_to_vworld = result.getLocalToVworld();
local_to_vworld.transform(insectPt);
```

Never needed it before as my triangle strips were added without a transform.

Comment: It won't let me. Besides my wife says I'm never right :-)